# How come a 4 core intel chip has the same TDP as a 6 core intel chip

Tags: cpu

This has been puzzling me for a while.

Here is the definition of TDP from intel spec sheets:

> Thermal Design Power (TDP) represents the average power, in watts, the
>   processor dissipates when operating at Base Frequency with all cores
>   active under an Intel-defined, high-complexity workload

Now, how come the i5-9300H and the i7-9850H have the same TDP?

The latter has both more cores and higher base frequency and they are both from the same generation of chips.

Comment: because the clock frequencies are dynamically adjusted downward, to achieve a safe maximum silicon temperature?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf: isn't your claim incompatible with the part of the quote that reads *[..]when operating at Base Frequency [...]*?

Comment: It greatly depends if the spec sheet was written by an engineer or a marketeer. I can imagine a marketeer would love a word like *base frequency* because it has no meaning.

Comment: In this context, base frequency is defined as (intel ARK page, above the quote in the question): *Processor Base Frequency describes the rate at which the processor's transistors open and close. The processor base frequency is the operating point where TDP is defined.* Does this mean that base frequency is not a constant (but depend on TDP)?

Comment: @user189035 That's a circular definition, almost certainly written by a marketer.

Comment: Ok, to close this: does this mean that under duress, if we fix the TDP to 45W, the  i7-9850H will reduce it's clock to roughly 4/6th of that of the i5-9300H?